# Pass variable as parameter to awk file in TCL

Tags: variables, awk, parameters, tcl

I want to pass variable to awk file in TCL which is somewhat similar to below code. Is there any way?
 // out.tr is input file and variable to be passed is to_node
my_code.tcl:

```
set to_node 13
exec awk -f check_ack.awk out.tr $to_node
```

check_ack.awk:

```
  BEGIN {}
    {
    # variable passed should be saved in node[i] --> But this doesnot work
    for ( i = 0; i < ARGC; i++ ) {
           node[i] = ARGV[i]
       }
    status = $7
        if(FILENAME=="trace.tr") {
            if(node[1] > -1 && $1  == "s" node[1] == $3 && status == "ack") {
            print "Node" " "node[1]" " "has not sent acknowledgement" >         "failed.txt"
            }
        }
    }
    END {
    exit 0
    }
```

Comment: This is really just an awk problem; Tcl's sending the value exactly as requested…

Comment: Yes. This is purely related to awk and awk is not identifying the variable which is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass variables like this:

```
awk -f some/script.awk -v var="my value"
```

Now you can access your variable `var` in awk and if you print it, you'll see it contains `my value`.

Comment: hi.. I get error with what you suggested. Please help me.  (FILENAME=trace.tr FNR=375251) fatal: cannot open file `-v' for reading (No such file or directory)
    while executing
"exec awk -f check_ack.awk trace.tr -v var=$to_node"

Comment: Supply the `-v` option first, like this: `exec awk -f check_ack.awk -v var=$to_node trace.tr `.

Comment: You can thank me by accepting the answer and upvoting it if you deemed it a quality answer! My pleasure btw!